# Using a variable to select a JSON array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

Is it possible to supply a variable to select a particular element within a JSON array element in order to select it?

Assuming I have many users:

```
"users": [
    { "id":"000000", "uname": "admin", "password": "admin", "phash": "b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e07394c706a8bb980b1d7785e5976ec049b46df5f1326af5a2ea6d103fd07c95385ffab0cacbc86",
        "profile": {
            "fullname"  : "Admin Admin",
            "datejoined": "01-01-2014",
            "reputation": "100",
            "displaypic": "http://www.google.com/logo.png",
            "cart": {
                "Cid" : "1000000",
                "item": [
                    { "Iid": "00000001", "quantity": "10" }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Is it possible to select the above element by supplying just the username using jQuery?

I have tried:
Note: uname in the jQuery is a variable with "admin" assigned

```
$.getJSON('ssUsers.json', function (data) {

        $(data.users[uname].profile.cart.item).each(function () {
            ++cartItems;
        });
```

With little luck:

[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.users[uname].profile')

Comment: I could not see profile in jSON

Comment: Wouldnt it by easier (and probably the best solution) that the key `users` is the `id` of the user? : `'000000' : [{...}]`

Answer (score 1):

Using [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
thisUser = $.grep(data.users, function(e) { return e.uname==uname});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
$.getJSON('ssUsers.json', function (data) {

        for(i=0; i<data.users.length ; i++){
            $(data.users[i].uname.profile.cart.item).each(function () {
                ++cartItems;

            }
        });
```

Comment: This would work, but I have many users but this would only work for the first user

Comment: But "profile" is not under "uname", That code should fail, shouldn't it ?